# Theory of operation of BJT transistor

Tags: untagged

In NPN BJT transistor, I know that the electrons is pulled by the reverse voltage in the np junction at the collector side

But why can't the flow of electrons take the route that I have drawed in the picture (the green one) why can't the voltage of the VBE pull all the charges and make it move like the green arrow?

[image]